# No Suitable HttpMessageConverter exception on calling postForObject for custom object

Tags: android, spring

I am trying to post a custom object using `postForObject` method. It throws below exception:

> org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException : Could not write
>   request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type
>   [com.test.MyClass]

The calling part is as below:

```
private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(true);
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new SimpleXmlHttpMessageConverter());
String response = restTemplate.postForObject(url, myClass, String.class);
```

`myClass` in an object of `MyClass`. The service expects xml representation of `myClass` object.

The `MyClass` definition is as below:

```
public class MyClass
{

private long id_;
private String info_;
private long token_;

public long getId() {
return id_;
}

public String getInfo() {
return info_;
}

public long getToken() {
return token_;
}
public void setId(long id_) {
this.id_ = id_;
}

public void setInfo(String info_) {
this.info_ = info_;
}

public void setToken(long token_) {
this.token_ = token_;
}
}
```

As, it looks like the `HttpMessageConverter` is not suitable, can someone suggest me how to write a custom `HttpMessageConverter` which can work with `myClass` object? Or any alternate approach?

Comment: Try restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());

Comment: I tried that, it gives me, org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request. Will JacksonHttpMessageConverter() help me on this? Because I'm dealing with Object which has to be serialized to xml.

Comment: Ok, i did not know that.  I thought you were submitting POJO to server and are developing both client and server.

Comment: I did read up about simple xml framework that you are trying to use.  It requires that POJOs be annotated so that it can be converted to XML.  You can read here : http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#start   Your POJO is not annotated, I guess thats why you are getting that error.

Comment: I am using annotated POJO and SimpleXmlHttpMessageConverter now. It gives me org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request. Not sure how to fix this.